# How can I get all controls on a form to expand out and increase proportionally in size when form is maximized?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

I have a form that is pretty large in the IDE at design time (905 X 813).

I added this code to make the form full screen:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TopMost = true;
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

...but the controls hug the Northwest corner and still leave a lot of "dead space", as the form is magnetized to the northwest corner, rather than its controls growing in size.

How can I get the controls to expand in all directions, filling the entire screen?

This doesn't need to take into consideration different monitor sizes or such - it is simply a mockup.

I tried to set the outer Panel's Anchor property to the middle/"all" setting, but it won't allow me - it stays on "Top, Left"...?!?

Comment: You can use [`Anchor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `Control` to set the behavior of `Control` when its parent is resizes.

Comment: I tried to change the Anchor of the outer panel, and it won't let me - it stays at the default Top, Left.

Comment: Usually I put all my controls in a Grid. and I design my Grid to be a 2d container(add rows and columns to it) were every control takes spot(s) and I "lock" its size to its spot(s). Then I "lock" the whole grid with its parent (form).. This way when the form expands, the grid expands, and all its rows/columnss too, equally => Therefore all controls follow the expand equally ;)

Comment: @RezaAghaei: It's just a plain panel from the Toolbox.

Comment: You should simply drag a panel from `ToolBox` and drop it the form and set its `Anchor` property to all sides. Surely it's location will remain the same, but it will resize when the form resizes. The distance of edges of panel and edges of form will not change.

Comment: @FirstStep: What sort of Grid - the only grid i see in the Toolbox  (besides PropertyGrid) is DataGridView...

Comment: `TableLayoutPabel` provides grid layout in WinForms.

Comment: As @RezaAghaei just beat me to it, it is a `TableLayoutPabel` which its equivalence in Wpf is `Grid`

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Did you try changing the value by text or by opening the dropdown and selecting all 4 edges?

Comment: @RezaAghaei: I tried doing it via the Properties in the IDE

Comment: Yes I know, but you typed in the property value or used the editor which open when you click on dropdown in front of `Anchor` property? [This Image](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC5072.gif)

Comment: So controls within a TableLayoutPanel will grow when the form is maximized?

Comment: @RezaAghaei: I clicked on the images.

Comment: And then pressed Escape? (It's the only way I can imagine you use the designer but the value doesn't change!)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon it not a default behavior that within a Grid, controls just grow when the form grows. It is just a good hack to use it. Each control follows its slot -> each slot follows the Grid -> the Grid follows the form

Comment: @RezaAghaei: No, I was clicking in the wrong place - in the quadrants instead of the strips; still, though, that only expands the panel, not the controls within the panel.

Comment: @FirstStep: So what you're saying is the controls remain the same size, and the space between them increases?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon  Oops!!! That was really hard to guess ;) OK - So just use  Anchor. It's enough. Use `TableLayoutPanel` when you need percent sizing rules.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon if you anchor to all 4 sides, the control will retain its size ratio according to the size of its parent, in this case its slot. So when the form grows, the slots grow, therefore forcing all controls to grow in SIZE

Comment: @RezaAghaei: With the Panel set to all Anchor edges, I then set a couple of controls to the same, but they don't change, and remain stuck in the NW corner - although the Panel itself does expand out.

Comment: It's pretty simple. It's not complicated. Start with a clean form to find your way. Also take a look at these links: [Windows Forms Layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951306.aspx) and [Walkthrough: Arranging Controls on Windows Forms Using a TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4yc3e8c(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Downvotes by invisible downvoters are really annoying and useless. I also believe your question can be improved to be more useful, but at least they can leave a comment if they think the post is not useful and ask for information which makes the post better.

Comment: Yes; perhaps downvotes should be disallowed without a stated reason.

Comment: You should make your outer-most `Panel` use `Dock.Fill` rather than `Anchor.*`

Comment: @MickyD: Dock.Fill makes it hug the outer borders of the form; I want the panel to serve as a visual border within the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too much clear to me... You can utilize ANCHOR, enabling LEFT and RIGHT to make the control grow to right direction, and disabling LEFT to make it "walk" through the form. Certainly doing a task on each control you will achieve the desirable position/size for them.

Anyway, you can manually index all positions and sizes of all controls using variables to get WIDTH and HEIGHT and calculate a kind of index. It is a big task to do but it enables you to control exactly each control position and height.

Bu if you want to redim the controls keeping all proportions (I mean, changing their FONT size), maybe this code may help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1025766/VB-NET-Dynamically-Resize-and-Reposition-All-Contr

Comment: My outermost control, a Panel, does not allow me to change its Anchor property.

Comment: You may consider work without the panel if it is there just for anchorage.

Comment: Doesn´t your panel allow you set as Left, Top, Right, Bottom?  Click over the rightmost arrow in its properties and set all boundaries.

Comment: I was doing it wrong; I realize now that you have to click on the strips, not the quadrants. Still, though, all that does is expand the panel. What do I need to do with the inner controls to get them to "ride along with" the Panel?

Comment: You may set their ANCHOR property, each one, to properly adapt itself to the panel.

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This video can help you too, even being in VB which does not differ to your case.

Comment: I have no capability for videos here; as for setting the Anchor property for the controls, what would they need to be set to? I tried setting a couple the same as the Panel, and it makes no difference.

Comment: You must set each one, individually. If there is not functioning at all, move them outside the panel and set each one individually to the form itself. Use the same procedure you utilized applied to panel. Or see the doc I recommended above the video.

Comment: I tried both setting controls within the panel and outside the panel to all anchor points, and although there was an effect, it was not pretty: it made them bigger than Godzilla and King Kong combined.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon _"My outermost control, a Panel, does not allow me to change its Anchor property"_ - use `Dock.Fill` instead

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in Wpf, I put all my controls in a `Grid` were every control takes spot(s) of its rows and columns. And I "lock" each control's size to its spot(s) by setting its size to `Auto`. Then I "lock" (`size="Auto"`) the whole Grid with its parent, the Form. This way when the Form expands, the Grid expands, all its rows/columns expands, equally => Therefore all controls follow the expand equally.

In Winform, you could ise the `TableLayoutPabel` which is the equivalence of Grid in Wpf. Now, if you anchor to all 4 sides, the control will retain its size ratio according to the size of its parent, in this case its slot. So when the form grows, the slots grow, therefore forcing all controls to grow in SIZE.

Comment: Can, as in WPF and HTML, a control span more than one columns or rows?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Yes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171687(v=vs.110).aspx